# Confused about how to work with List<string>[]

Tags: c#, mysql, arrays, listview

I'm learning on how to access MySQL database using C#
by following [this guide](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43438/Connect-C-to-MySQL)

In those codes, it uses `List<string>[4]` to store the Selected data because it has 4 columns

After some experiment, I found out that those codes store the data in a format like this:

```
//List[0] = Name1, Name2, Name3, ...

//List[1] = Age1, Age2, Age3, ...

//...
```

I want to access the data **row by row** and display it in `ListView`,

but if we use `foreach`, it will list the data **column by column**

```
foreach (List<string> entry in dataEntries){
    ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(entry[0]); //refer to Name1 during first loop

    lvi.SubItems.Add(entry[1]); //Name2
    lvi.SubItems.Add(entry[2]); //Name3
    lvi.SubItems.Add(entry[3]); //and so on
    listView1.Items.Add(lvi);
}
```

Is there a way to display it row by row? Or is there any simpler workaround?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: A datatable was not good enough for this?

Comment: The guide you are following is not a good one.

Comment: @MennanKara - That is the understatement of the year.

Comment: Basically I have two class, one for GUI and one for Database
so Database class only hold the query to access database
GUI only for form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part of the tutorial:

```
public List< string >[] Select()
{
    string query = "SELECT * FROM tableinfo";

    //Create a list to store the result
    List< string >[] list = new List< string >[3];
    list[0] = new List< string >();
    list[1] = new List< string >();
    list[2] = new List< string >();

    //Open connection
    if (this.OpenConnection() == true)
    {
        //Create Command
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
        //Create a data reader and Execute the command
        MySqlDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        //Read the data and store them in the list
        while (dataReader.Read())
        {
            list[0].Add(dataReader["id"] + "");
            list[1].Add(dataReader["name"] + "");
            list[2].Add(dataReader["age"] + "");
        }

        //close Data Reader
        dataReader.Close();

        //close Connection
        this.CloseConnection();

        //return list to be displayed
        return list;
    }
    else
    {
        return list;
    }
}
```

is what you're referring to, I suppose. It's not a good way to store the results, and it's rather poorly-written to boot. You could just as easily do:

```
public List<object[]> Select() {
    string query = "SELECT * FROM tableinfo";

    // Create a list to store the result
    var result = new List<object[]>();

    // Open connection
    if (this.OpenConnection()) {
        // Create Command
        var cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
        // Create a data reader and Execute the command
        MySqlDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        // Read the data and store them in the list
        while(dataReader.Read()) {
            object[] items = new object[dataReader.FieldCount];
            dataReader.GetValues(items);
            result.Add(items);
        }

        // Close Data Reader
        dataReader.Close();

        // Close Connection
        this.CloseConnection();

        // Return list to be displayed
        return list;
    } else {
        // This is a bad thing.
        throw new ApplicationException("Could not connect to database.");
    }
}
```

And if I recall database access correctly, this is how you're supposed to do it:

```
public DataSet Select() {
    if(!this.OpenConnection()) {
        throw new ApplicationException("Could not connect to database.");
    }

    using(var query = new MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM tableinfo", this.connection)) {
        var data = new DataSet();

        query.Fill(data);

        return data;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! You are worthy of having 45k reputation

Answer (score 2):

Yes this article is quite bad.  I put the code from the article at the end.  Here is how I would do it:

Note: I made everything a string as he did, which seems wrong.  Also, I did not test so there might be typos.

```
class DataItem 
{
   public string id { get; set; }
   public string name { get; set; }
   public string age { get; set; }
}

//Select statement
public List<DataITem> Select()
{
    string query = "SELECT * FROM tableinfo";

    //Create a list to store the result
    List<DataItem> list = new List<DateItem>();

    //Open connection
    if (this.OpenConnection())
    {
        //Create Command
        using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection))
        {
           //Create a data reader and Execute the command
           using (MySqlDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
           {

              //Read the data and store them in the list
              while (dataReader.Read())
              {
                 list.Add(new DataItem() { id = dataReader["id"] + "",
                                           name = dataReader["name"] + "",
                                           age = dataReader["age"] + "" });
              }
           }

        }

        this.CloseConnection();
    }

    return list;
}
```

Code from article:

```
//Select statement
public List< string >[] Select()
{
    string query = "SELECT * FROM tableinfo";

    //Create a list to store the result
    List< string >[] list = new List< string >[3];
    list[0] = new List< string >();
    list[1] = new List< string >();
    list[2] = new List< string >();

    //Open connection
    if (this.OpenConnection() == true)
    {
        //Create Command
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
        //Create a data reader and Execute the command
        MySqlDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        //Read the data and store them in the list
        while (dataReader.Read())
        {
            list[0].Add(dataReader["id"] + "");
            list[1].Add(dataReader["name"] + "");
            list[2].Add(dataReader["age"] + "");
        }

        //close Data Reader
        dataReader.Close();

        //close Connection
        this.CloseConnection();

        //return list to be displayed
        return list;
    }
    else
    {
        return list;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But can I change the `using(MySql...)` to become like in the original article? Are those parts work differently?

Comment: Sure just pull out the while part and put in the original code if you want -- `using()` is best practice, but why bother?

Comment: Thanks man, your code works! But @minitech reply is cleaner and I think it keeps the original data type from the database.
Cheers :)